# k-th smallest element in sliding segment

Tags: data-structures, heaps

Consider an array $a[1\ldots n]$ and another array $l = a[0]$ (initial value). At each turn we may add next element to array $l$, or remove first element from array $l$. F.e. after first iteration it could be empty or could become $a[0, 1]$. We want to find k-th smallest element at each iteration in array $l$.

First of all if size of $l$ is less than $k$ the answer is 'No'. Let's consider more interesting case.

I've decided to have two heaps (one min and one max heap).

Max heap contains all k-th smallest elements from $a[l..r]$ and min heap contains elements which are greater than the k-th smallest element. Then answer is head of max-heap (we can take it in O(1)).

But there is a small problem. What if need to consider $a[l+1 .. r]$ (so we need to push left bound). Now of course if $r - l < k$ the answer is 'No', but what should we do otherwise? I thought we should do following: if $a[l] > maxheap[0]$ then the answer doesn't change (because we will delete element greater than k-th smallest element), but what should we do with our heaps? Unfortunately I can't delete in heap by position (it takes a long time). The best we can do is delete root node in O(log n). How should I affect them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain an AVL tree $B$ that stores the elements in $l$.
In addition, for each element $a$ in $l$, keep a pointer $p_a$ to the corresponding node in $B$.

- When an element $x$ is added to $l$, then simply insert a new node $v$ representing $x$ into $B$ and make $p_x$ point to $v$.
- When the first element $y$ of $l$ needs to be removed, delete (the node pointed by) $p_y$ from $B$.
- To report the $k$-minimum element in $l$, simply look for the minimum element in $B$ (i.e., the one stored in the leftmost node). This can be done in $O(\log n)$ time by just keeping, in each node $v$, the size of the subtree of $B$ rooted in $v$.

By combining the above operations, each turn of your problem will require $O(\log(1 + |l|)) = O(\log n)$ time.

Comment: I don't need minimum. I need k-th minimum.

Comment: And BST would give me O(k log n) per each operation. It's too long. Even quick-select would give O(n) in worst case

Comment: @openspace As I said, if you choose to implement your BST using AVL trees then you get a time of $O(\log n)$ per operation.

Comment: @openspace, sorry about that. I fixed the answer. It doesn't really matter what element you're looking for. In an AVL tree of $n$ elements the element with a given rank can be found in $O(\log n)$ time.

Comment: how we determine the rank? K-th element could be in any place of tree. At least I'd need to make O(k log n) traverse operations.

Comment: okay what's rank then?

Comment: You don't need to traverse the whole tree to find the element with rank $k$. $B$ satisfies the BST property so if the number of nodes $\eta$ in the subtree $T$ of $B$ rooted in the left child of the root $r$ is larger than $k$, you can search for the element with rank $k$ in $T$. If $\eta=k-1$, you return $r$, and if $\eta<k-1$ you can search for the element with rank $k-\eta-1$ in the subtree of $B$ rooted in the right child of the root. Since the height $h$ of $B$ is $O(\log n)$ and you can recurse at most $h$ times, the claim on the time complexity follows.

Comment: I guess I understand you. Sorry! But what about heaps?

Comment: If you have a pointer to a node in a heap, you can actually delete the corresponding element in $O(\log n)$ time. If you are familiar with the decrease-key operation, think of decreasing the element's key to $-\infty$ (in a min-heap) and then pop()-ing the minimum element. Then you can also implement the operations using a max-heap, a min-heap and, for each element $a$, a pointer $p_a$ to the corresponding node in the heap currently containing $a$ (if any).

Comment: you mean delete element by position, not the head element?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115342/discussion-between-steven-and-openspace).